# Object reference not set to instance of an object in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a service where i am trying to add new users. If the user already exsists it should not add  but i am getting an error."Object reference set to instance an object"

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string AddUsers(UsersJSON UserJSON)
    {
        using (var context = new Data.DataEntities())
        {
            var users = context.Users.Where(c => c.UserId == UserJson.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
            var newuser = new Users();
            {
                if (users.UserId != UserJson.UserId)//error here
                {
                    newuser.UserId = UserJson.UserId;
                    newuser.FirstName = UserJson.FirstName;
                    newuser.LastName = UserJson.LastName;

                }
            }
            context.Users.Add(newuser);
            context.SaveChanges();
            JavaScriptSerializer JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return JSON.Serialize(newuser);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @mason: To be honest that's not very helpful.

Comment: How exactly are you testing if a user does not exist? Are you even doing the test?

Comment: You forgot one very important information - where exactly is that exception thrown? How would you like to fix an error, which you don't know where is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.FirstOrDefault` which can possibly return null. So you need to guard against that.

```
var users = context.Erp_Users.Where(c => c.UserId == erpUserJson.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
var newuser = new Erp_Users();
{
    if (users != null && users.UserId != erpUserJson.UserId)//no error here
    {
        ...
```

Comment: if i do like its breaking after savechanges() .